# Image resolution too low when uploaded from Facebook messenger

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building a bot where a user can upload image from their gallery or take a picture.

Facebook messenger provides this to my bot as image_url which when i download provides an image with really low dpi, my backend API runs an OCR on these uploaded images and requires this to above certain DPI.

Is there a way to get better quality images from Facebook ?

It worked initially by enabling the switch in settings as given below in the answer but it has stopped again, not sure why ?

Comment: I am experiencing the same and it is pretty frustrating! And the photo is really good quality for the person, but not the image the webhook receive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is not a code level solution, this should get fixed when a modification is done from the client end on their main Facebook application. For instructions follow,

https://www.facebook.com/help/iphone-app/187741037945488?helpref=faq_content

Comment: Thats it. It worked. I wish there was a solution from the code side where we as bot developers can specify this.

Comment: Some issues occurred and its not working anymore. I have upload HD photos in my settings but still my images are coming back as low DPI.

Comment: Is it same for images that previously had no issues ?